# How to go to a particular line in Zend Studio 12 with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-studio

What is the shortcut to go to a particular line in Zend Studio 12, in the same way that <kbd>CTRL + G</kbd> works in NetBeans IDE and Notepad++?

Also, how can I get all the shortcuts of Zend Studio 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL + L</kbd> is the short cut to go to line directly.

If you want to see a full list of shortcuts, in Zend Studio go to :

**Window--> Preferences--> General--> Keys.**

To bring up a list of commonly used commands, press <kbd>Ctrl+ Shift+ L</kbd> in the Editor.

Source : [commonly used keyboard shortcuts](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/keymap.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Manage

- Ctrl + N Add New Document
- Ctrl + O Open Document
- Ctrl + F4 Close Document/Window
- Ctrl + Shft + F4 Close All
- Ctrl + Shft + O Open Project
- Ctrl + Shft + N New Project
- Ctrl + S Save File
- Ctrl + Shft + S Save As
- Ctrl + Alt + S Save All

Editor

- Ctrl + Space Show Code Completion
- Ctrl + Space + Shft Show Function Arguments
- Ctrl + Shft + F Reformat Code
- Ctrl + / Add Remove Comment
- Ctrl + / + Shft Add Remove PHP Block Comment
- Ctrl + W Toggle Line Wrap
- Ctrl + Z Undo
- Ctrl + Y Redo
- Ctrl + E Erase Line
- Ctrl + D Duplicate Selection
- Ctrl + L Change Selection to Lower Case
- Ctrl + U Change Selection to Upper Case
- Ctrl + B Bold Tag
- Alt + I Italic Tag
- Ctrl + - [1-3] Heading 1-3 Tag
- Ctrl + Enter Break Tag
- Ctrl + Back + Quote NBSP Tag
- F1 Open Function Help

Code Folding

- Ctrl + Shft + 1 Collapse All Non-PHP
- Ctrl + Shft + 2 Collapse All Classes
- Ctrl + Shft + 3 Collapse All Functions
- Ctrl + Shft + 4 Collapse All DocBlocks
- Ctrl + Shft + 9 Fold in Scope
- Ctrl + Shft + E Expand All Folds
- Ctrl + Shft + C Collapse All Folds

Debugging & Profiling

- F8 Debug URL
- F12 Profile URL
- Ctrl + F5 Run
- F5 Go
- F10 Step Over
- F11 Step Into
- Shft + F1 1 Step Out
- Shft + F5 Stop Debug
- Shft + F10 Go to Cursor
- F9 Toggle Breakpoint
- Shft + F8 Add Watch
- Ctrl + Alt + B Show In Browser

Navigation

- Ctrl + Alt + G Goto File
- Ctrl + Shft + G Goto PHP Resource
- Ctrl + G Goto Line
- Ctrl + F2 Goto Next Bookmark
- Alt + F2 Goto Next Project Bookmark
- Ctrl + M Goto Matching Bracket
- Alt + Left/Right Go Back/Forward
- F2 Toggle Bookmark
- Ctrl + Shft + F2 Remove All Bookmarks
- Ctrl + Shft + M Open Bookmarks Dialog
- Ctrl + Shft + R Show Recent Files
- F4 Open Next Entry

Find/Replace

- Ctrl + F Find
- F3 Find Next
- Shft + F3 Find Prev
- Ctrl + H Replace
- Ctrl + Alt + F Find In Files

CVS/Subversion

- Alt + U Update
- Alt + C Commit

Tools

- Alt + Ctrl + A Analyze Code
- Ctrl + Shft + I Check Include Files